# Filter setup error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm following [this](http://www.codeheaps.com/php-programming/building-user-authentication-in-laravel-4-part-1/) tutorial and creating a very simple Login system, but I'm getting an error here:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter(function()
        {
            if(Auth::guest()) //check if logged in
                return Redirect::to('admin/login');
        }, ['except' => ['getLogin','postLogin']]);
    }
```

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException syntax
>   error, unexpected '['

Here:

> }, ['except' => ['getLogin','postLogin']]);

Comment: Check my answer then. Square bracket initializer was introduced in php  5.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably run version  `PHP < 5.4`.
Square bracket array initialization (`[...]`) was introduced in `PHP 5.4`.

Try using [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) or update PHP.

#### Array version

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter(
            function(){
                if(Auth::guest()){ //check if logged in
                    return Redirect::to('admin/login');
                }
            },
            array('except' => array('getLogin','postLogin'))
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a closing bracket

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter(function()
    {
        if(Auth::guest()) //check if logged in
            return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    }, ['except' => ['getLogin','postLogin']]);
}

}
```